# Select count of places within given distance

Tags: mysql

I have a set of coordinates:

```
$lat = 29.425921; 
$lon = -98.486178;
```

I would like to query my table and select results within 10 miles. I believe it's possible to do within a query. Unfortunately my db version is 5.6 and I can't use latest spacial functions. How can I do that? Based on examples I came across I cobbled together something like this.

```
SELECT name,  
  111.1111 *
  DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(".$lat."))
     * COS(RADIANS(t1.lat))
     * COS(RADIANS(".$lon.") - RADIANS(t1.lon))
     + SIN(RADIANS(".$lat."))
     * SIN(RADIANS(t1.lat))))) AS distance
FROM t1
```

Comment: And did that work? If not, why not?

Comment: Actually it did. Initially I only saw NULL, but when I modified the queryto match only those that have lat and lon and not NULL it worked. Cheers.

Comment: Now I still need to add a condition to search withing 10 miles. Also, I think the results are in kilometers. How do I convert to miles?

Comment: If only there was some way of searching for that kind of stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you query now works as desired (like you mentioned in your own comment) you should be able to limit the distance like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT name,  
    111.1111 *
    DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(".$lat."))
       * COS(RADIANS(t1.lat))
       * COS(RADIANS(".$lon.") - RADIANS(t1.lon))
       + SIN(RADIANS(".$lat."))
       * SIN(RADIANS(t1.lat))))) AS distance
  FROM t1
) WHERE distance < 10
```

This is necessary because `distance` is a *calculated column*. MySQL evaluates your `WHERE` clause before the `SELECT` part, so `distance` doesn't yet exist at that point. By nesting your query you make sure that your columns are calculated first and can be used in the outer level.

Comment: I get "unknown column distance" error message.

Comment: Had to "AS dis" before "WHERE distance < 10" to avoid “Every derived table must have its own alias” Error in MySQL but it worked great! Thanks.